# Como validar origem do formulario?

Tags: php, html, formulário, post

Eu tenho uma aplicação web no qual existe um  formulário de login e registro, e pelo que percebi eu posso baixa o HTML do meu site e manda requisição pelo meu PC apontando para o site, então como eu verifico a origem do formulário?

Comment: Com id/token de uma sessão ou um captcha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diferentes maneiras de fazer, a primeira e talvez a mais usar é o "anti-CRSF" (se é que pode-se chamar assim):

autenticar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token'], $_POST['login'], $_POST['senha'])) {
    $token = empty($_SESSION['token']) ? NULL : $_SESSION['token'];

    //Compara o token com o post
    if ($_POST['token'] === $token) {
         /*Valida $_POST['login'] e $_POST['senha']*/
    } else {
         echo 'Requisição invalida';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Faltam dados no Form';
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//Cria um token
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
?>

<form method="POST" action="autenticar.php">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<? php echo $_SESSION['token']?>" />
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login"><br>
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="senha"><br>
<button type="submit">Logar</button>
</form>
```

Desta maneira você cria um token e salva ele na sessão, na próxima página você verifica o POST e a sessão, se ambos tiverem valores iguais significa que o veio da mesma origem, isso é um exemplo bem básico, existe ainda um exemplo que tenta fazer dificultar mais ainda isto, nele todos os campos tem chaves randomicas, segue exemplo:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116437/3635

A outra maneira é verificar o referer, por exemplo:

- `http://exemplo/paginaA.php`

  ```
  <form method="POST" action="paginaB.php">
  <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login"><br>
  <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="senha"><br>
  <button type="submit">Logar</button>
  </form>
  ```
- `http://exemplo/paginaB.php`

  ```
  <?php
  if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'http://exemplo/paginaA.php') {
      echo 'Acesso bloqueado';
      exit;
  }

  //Resto do script
  ```

Note bem que o uso do `HTTP_REFERER` pode muitas vezes falhar e pode facilmente ser trapaceado usando plugin ou requisições por ferramentas como CURL, wget, etc e até mesmo plugins pra navegadores podem controlar os headers das requisições.

O anti-CRSF é considerado bem mais seguro, mas também pode ser trapaceado, no entanto é bem mais difícil fazer isto.

Resumindo não existe nada 100% seguro, mas os exemplos ajudam a prevenir.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta super explicativa, com a primeira solução o usuário pode baixa formulário com key e enviar varias vezes com tentativa de fazer um login, certo?

Comment: @Cleideson ele pode baixar o form com a key, mas ela é regenerada a todo momento, a key que ele baixar já será invalida quando tentar enviar uma requisição via form baixado ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado!